# Read Line From File Until Newline and Store it in Char Array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that reads one line from a file and stores it into a char array. Since I only want to read one line, I want it to stop reading at the newline. My current code doesn't achieve exactly what I want it to do. From a file that contains:

```
Hello
u
```

I want to store `Hello` in a char array. My current code only stores `llo` and some other garbage. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char random[100];

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("testing.txt", "r");
        if(fp == NULL){
            printf("Can't open the file\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    char c;

while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
    for(int i = 0; c != '\n'; i++){
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
        random[i] = c;
    }
}

printf("%s\n", random);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (fgets(random, sizeof random, stdin));` and you are done, your code fails because you consume a `byte` and fill `c` with `fgetc` and then refill `c` with `fscanf` (consuming another byte)

Comment: @DavidRanieri Could you elaborate a little? How does the line you wrote read from the file? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: `fgets`:  Reads at most count - 1 characters from the given file stream and stores them in the character array pointed to by str. Parsing stops if a newline character is found, in which case str will contain that newline character, or if end-of-file occurs. If bytes are read and no errors occur, writes a null character at the position immediately after the last character written to str.

Comment: Also, you need to take care of buffer overflows, what happens if user inputs more than 100 lines? With `fgets` your buffer is protected.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int` for a reason: `EOF` can not be represented as a `char` value.  So by putting the value from `fgetc()` into a `char`, you can not reliably detect the actual end of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){       <-- You consume a byte (H)
    for(int i = 0; c != '\n'; i++){
        fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);        <-- You consume another byte (E) and overwrite c
        random[i] = c;               <-- You read c (H) gets loosed
    }
}
```

and you don't check for buffer overflows, instead

```
char random[100] = ""; // Initialize, a string must be NUL terminated
int c, i = 0;

while (i < 99 && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n')
{
    random[i++] = c;
}
```

or better yet, use `fgets` and strip the trailing newline

```
if (fgets(random, sizeof random, fp))
{
    random[strcspn(random, "\n")] = '\0';
}
```

EDIT:

> Imagine the text file has a number in the first line and a word in the
> second ...

In this case, I will use `strtol`

```
int number = 0;
// Line 1 - read the int
if (fgets(random, sizeof random, fp))
{
    int number = (int)strtol(random, NULL, 10); // 10 means base 10 (decimal)

    // As pointed out by @chux in comments, if the line contains 
    // more than 100 chars you end up reading garbage in the next
    // call to fgets, sanitize the line:
    if (strchr(random, '\n') == NULL)
    {
        int c;

        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF); // flush garbage
    }
}
// Line 2 - read the string, you can reuse `random`:
if (fgets(random, sizeof random, fp))
{
    random[strcspn(random, "\n")] = '\0';
}
printf("%d %s\n", number, random);
```

Comment: This is beyond the original question but if you don't mind answering, I would appreciate it. If I were dealing with int rather than char, how would I strip the newline?  Imagine the text file has a number in the first line and a word in the second. I want to store that first line in an int and the second in a char array as we did here.

Comment: With `(c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n' && i < 99` and input is too long, the 100th `char` is lost.  `i < 99 && (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n'` prevents that loss.

Comment: "better yet, use fgets and strip the trailing newline" is a good idea yet it has a weakness: it obliges the caller to supply a buffer one longer than needed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well, it seems that OP wants a string of 99 chars + 1 for the NUL, but good to point that, OP, if you want an array able to store 100 characters, you need to use `char random[101] = "";` in order to set the traling `\0`

Comment: I think there is a + 2 need: If input line was 4 keys "abc\n", a returned _string_ of 3 characters, with the `fgets()` approach and reading in the whole line, would require a buffer of 3 + 2.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I don't get you, `fgets` includes the new line but it reads at most count - 1 characters, so  if the fle contains `abc\n` it will fit in a `char[4]`, and there is no need to use a `char[5]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226161/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-david-ranieri).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c, i = 0;
    char hash[100] = "";

    printf("INPUT::\n");
    while (i < 99 && (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        hash[i++] = (char)c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am a beginner but hope this might helps.
You may uncomment the last 2 lines to check that your data is in the array.

Comment: What happens with `hash[0]`?, why an array of `int`s? why `j`? why `getchar()` if OP is reading a file?

Comment: hash[10] is an array the guy wanted it to store it in an array. j is just complimentary for testing the program sthrough the printf fxn declared as comment. getchar() is a fxn specifically used to read word by word. I AM A BEGINNER TO CODING SO PARDON IF I MISUNDERSTOOD THE PROB..

Comment: No problem Samarthya, we have all been beginners. The main problem with your code is this `hash[0]` uninitialized, this can introduce a lot of bugs, since C is a 0 based array language, start writting at index 0.  And well ... OP wants to read the first line of a file into a string (an array of `char`s ), you are reading an array of `int`s from `stdin`. Correct those points and you will receive an UPVOTE :)

Comment: I've edited as far as I understood the problems. You are great thanks. Any input is very welcomed.

Comment: "Any input is very welcomed." --> Test  `i` first. [rational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366064/read-line-from-file-until-newline-and-store-it-in-char-array#comment115563802_65366178).